# Is it possible to run php-fpm with swoole?

Tags: php, apache, websocket, fpm, swoole

Online search is saying php-fpm vs swoole, that swoole replaces the need for it. But I use php-fpm so that I can control which php version each directory uses via a handler. One of the php versions I'm running uses php 5.4, so if swoole has some way to make a handler for multiple versions, I suppose I can just turn off the fpm services for my higher versions and use a swoole handler in htaccess equivalent, if that even exists. I'm wanting to use websockets, and since its a pet project I found a repo on github that has multithreaded websockets in php using parallel, though I'm a bit out of my scope here.